# Git upload to live site after qa approved

Tags: git, github, workflow, project-management, bitbucket

I am new to Git stuff but I know how to add/commit/push/pull changes.

**Situation:**

We have a git-managed project (currently on bitbucket)

Now we are setting up QA and Live places. So for example if we made feature X and pushed to QA and client approves it, we should then be able to push our changes to Live/Production site.

So here is how flow would be like:

- Changes made locally
- Changes pushed to QA/Dev folder
- Client okayed, changes pushed to Live/Production folder

Can somebody help how to achieve this workflow ? I am not really sure what's needed for this flow

`local ---> dev ---> production`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of many methods to realize this workflow is to use a workflow called **git flow**, see [this link](http://nvie.com/git-model/) for more details.

To summarize, in this workflow you've got a production branch - the `master` branch - and a development - the `develop` branch. Your developers are creating features based on this develop branch, implementing and testing them and merging them back to the develop branch.

If the feature set is complete for a specific release a new `release` branch is created where, for example, the QA can test the new release. After the QA is happy, the branch is merged back to the develop as well as to the master branch, where the client can now get the new working release.

Have a look on the link above for a more detailed explanation.